# An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObjectTagging operation: Access Denied Even sync from public bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The line that I am trying to run is

```
aws s3 sync s3://sourcebucket.publicfiles s3://mybucket
```

I have been looking through multiple question like this and I have tried about everything.

I have changed my IAM policy to give full access

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListStorageLensConfigurations",
                "s3:ListAccessPointsForObjectLambda",
                "s3:GetAccessPoint",
                "s3:PutAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:GetAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:ListAccessPoints",
                "s3:ListJobs",
                "s3:PutStorageLensConfiguration",
                "s3:ListMultiRegionAccessPoints",
                "s3:CreateJob"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3::ID:accesspoint/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:*:ID:accesspoint/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:us-west-2:ID:async-request/mrap/*/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::*/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:*:938745241482:storage-lens/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:*:938745241482:job/*",
                "arn:aws:s3-object-lambda:*:ID:accesspoint/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

As well as the bucket policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "statement",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ID:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

At this point I have tried making my bucket public as well as

`aws s3 cp s3://sourcebucket.publicfiles/file  s3://mybucket/file --acl bucket-owner-full-control`

for the specific files that are not working but it gives me the same error.

> An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObjectTagging operation: Access Denied

Since this is a public bucket I do not have access to its policies.

I am not sure what else to try so I would really appreciate any insight

PS This is my first post here so if there is a better way to format question/ any more info I should give I am sorry

Answer (score 3):

The error is saying that you do not have permission to call `GetObjectTagging`. This indicates that the Copy operation is attempting to retrieve Tags from the object so that it can then apply the same tags to the copied object, but you do not have permission to request the tags on the source object.

An article [Troubleshoot issues copying an object between S3 buckets](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-copy-between-buckets/) says:

> You must have s3:GetObjectTagging permission for the source object and s3:PutObjectTagging permission for objects in the destination bucket.

Therefore, if the source bucket is not granting you `GetObjectTagging` permission, then you cannot use `aws s3 sync` or `aws s3 cp`. Instead, you will need to **copy each object individually** using [`aws s3api copy-object`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/copy-object.html). For example:

```
aws s3api copy-object --copy-source bucket-1/test.txt --key test.txt --bucket bucket-2
```

(If I need to copy multiple objects individually, I make a list of objects in an Excel spreadsheet and then make a formula to create the above copy-object command. I use 'Copy Down' to create commands for all files, then paste all the commands into the command line.)